# Constructing a function $f$ over a metric space such that $K_1$ is bounded but $K_2$ is not

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $T:X\to X$ be a mapping. Let $\displaystyle K_1:=\frac{d(Tx,Ty)-\alpha. d (x,y)}{d(x,Tx)\cdot d(y,Ty)}$, and $\displaystyle K_2:=\frac{d(Tx,Ty)-\alpha\, d (x,y)}{d(x,Tx)}$ for all $x,y\in X$ and $\alpha \in [0,1)$.

> I want to find out such a function $T$ over a suitable complete metric space $X$ with a suitable metric $d$ such that $K_2$ is bounded above but for some $\alpha \in [0,1)$ but $K_1$ is unbounded for all $\alpha \in [0,1)$.

> Does there exist such a function ? If not, then how does "$K_2$ is bounded above" implies "$K_1$ is bounded above" ?

I have tried to show $K_1$ is bounded by letting $K_2$ is bounded. But unable to show. So my initial guess is that there exists such function. I've checked by constructing $X=\{\frac{1}{2^n}: n\in \Bbb N\}$ and $T:X\to X$ by $T(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ , but it does not help !

Can anyone help me to construct such a function ?

**Note:** Neglect the case when any one of $d(x,Tx)$ or $d(y,Ty)$ is zero. In which case any one is zero then it is sufficient to show that $d(Tx,Ty)\le \alpha. d(x,y)$.  So we can find out a mapping without any fixed point, in that case everywhere $K_1$ and $K_2$ are well-defined. If a mapping has a fixed point, say $c$ then it has to satisfy only $d(Tx,Tc)\le \alpha. d(x,c)$, for all $x\in X$ and for any other points $x,y\in X\setminus \{c\}$, we have to check the bounds for $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Help please..

Comment: Is $T=f$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: How are $K_1$ and $K_2$ defined if $Tx=x$ or $Ty=y$?

Comment: It seems like just about any function $T$ that increases distances significantly should work. With $X=\Bbb R$, how about something like $Tx=x^2$ or $Tx=e^x$? Certainly $K_2$ is bounded (consider $y$ much larger than $x$ in absolute value).

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, good question...kindly wait for few minutes, I will update

Comment: @GregMartin I have updated it. please have a look in last note.

Comment: Is $T$ continuous? How do we need to treat the case of fixpoints if we want to prove that there is no such function?

Comment: @supinf NOT necessarily continuous. Don't bother about continuity. It may be continuous or may be not.. If there is no fixed point the everything is well defined. No prbolem at all

Answer (score 1):

As per the hint given by Greg in the comments, you can try $T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ maps $x \mapsto x^2$. For simplicity take $\alpha = 0$, but for $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ everything is the same.

Take $x > 0$, and consider a pair of points $(x, y) = (x, kx)$ for some parameter $k$. We have
$$ d(Tx, Ty) = k^2 x^2 - x^2 \approx k^2 x^2 $$
$$ d(x, Tx) = x^2 - x \approx x^2 $$
$$ d(y, Ty) = k^2 x^2 - kx \approx k^2 x^2 $$

Then
$$ K_1 \approx \frac{k^2 x^2}{k^2 x^4} $$
is bounded, while
$$ K_2 \approx \frac{k^2 x^2}{x^2} $$
is not bounded by choosing $k$ large. More specifically, the sequence $K_2(n, n^2)$ is unbounded.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry that I have written wrongly about K1 and K2..!! Actually I want the converse...That's why , I have tried with decreasing function...Please read my corrected question..

Comment: Actually I need example with K2 is bounded but K1 is not...Pardon me, and please try to understand that I want this type of example, and that's why I tried with decreasing function...but I have written wrongly...!! That's totally my mistake, and I appreciate your answer...Can you please see the corrected question now?

Comment: Ah okay...no worries!